# Developing a Shiny App and got Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

The data is from [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022_per_game.html). I selected the "Get table as CSV (for Excel)" option from "Share & Export". I highlighted all the resulting table text, and copied to excel. I then did "Text to columns" and split the data by the comma delimiters. I then saved the file as a .csv extension. My goal is to create an app with sliders for minutes and games played with a check box for teams. I want plotly graphs with pop ups. My code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
Player_Stats<-read.csv("2021-2022 Indiv Per Game Stats.csv")
colnames(Player_Stats)[11]<-"FG%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[14]<-"ThreeP%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[17]<-"TwoP%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[18]<-"eFG%"
colnames(Player_Stats)[21]<-"FT%"
colnames(Player_Stats)

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Player Stats"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("input1",
                  "Minutes",
                  min=0,
                  max = max(MP),
                  value = 0),
      sliderInput("Input2",
                  "Games Played",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 82,
                  value = 0),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "tm_input",
                         label = "Team",
                         choices = unique(Player_Stats$Tm),
                         selected = unique(Player_Stats$Tm))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1"),
      plotOutput("plot2"),
      dataTableOutput("Player_StatsTable")
    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output){
  output$plot1<-renderPlotly({
    Player_Stats.subset() %>% ggplotly(
      ggplot(aes(x=PTS, y=`ThreeP%`,color=Tm, 
                 text=paste("Player:",Player, "PPG:",PTS, "3P%:", `ThreeP%`*100, "Team:",Tm)))+
        geom_point()+
        geom_smooth()+
        xlab("Points per Game")+
        ylab("Three Point %")+
        ggtitle("PPG and 3P% by Player")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    )
  })
  output$plot2<-renderPlotly({
    Player_Stats.subset() %>% ggplotly(
      ggplot(aes(x=PTS, y=`TwoP%`,color=Tm, 
                 text=paste("Player:",Player, "PPG:",PTS, "2P%:", `2P%`*100, "Team:",Tm)))+
        geom_point()+
        geom_smooth()+
        xlab("Points per Game")+
        ylab("Two Point %")+
        ggtitle("PPG and 2P% by Player")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    )
  })
  Player_Stats.subset=reactive({
    Player_Stats %>% 
      dplyr::filter(Tm %in% input$Tm_,.preserve = TRUE) %>%
      dplyr::filter(MP>=input$input1) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(G>=input$input2)
  })
  output$Player_StatsTable<-renderDataTable({
    Player_Stats.subset
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```